# Promise to do something after all rows from MySQL result are processed

Tags: mysql, node.js

Thanks in advance. I'm trying to do something after all rows from MySQL result is processed. I tried with Promises but It's not working.
Theres 4600 rows but I'm just getting []. I'm guessing my issue is NodeJS Async.
Here is my code:

```
let paradasRelations = db.query('SELECT * FROM ParadasRelations');

    let paradaPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let paradasData = [];
        paradasRelations.on('result', function (row) {
            paradasData.push(row);
        });
        resolve(paradasData);
    });
    paradaPromise.then(function (paradasData) {
        console.log(paradasData);
    });
```

Comment: try `paradasRelations.on('end', function (row) { resolve(paradasData);});`

Comment: Getting undefined

Comment: i had a typo in my suggestion, pls check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to resolve the `Promise` only after all the rows have been returned and you get an `end` event. This is untested but something like this should work:

```
let paradasRelations = db.query('SELECT * FROM ParadasRelations');

let paradaPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    let paradasData = [];
    paradasRelations.on('result', function (row) {
        paradasData.push(row);
    });

    paradasRelations.on('end', function () {
        resolve(paradasData);
    });
});

paradaPromise.then(function (paradasData) {
    console.log(paradasData);
});
```

Comment: np, don't forget to mark as the answer if you are happy :)